# Is it legal to make a vector of another companies product?

Tags: vector, business, legal

So I own a business that will soon start developing mobile apps for platforms such as the iPad. I am wondering if I can legally make a vector graphic of other companies products such as the iPad to put a photo of my application on. I will acquire an Apple Developer account and get the app(s) approved before I publish the graphics. Any insight into this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, no it is not okay.

There have been several topics here covering this:

[What is the copyright of fanart?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/12798/what-is-the-copyright-of-fanart)

[Who is the rightful copyright holder of images to Windows components?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4352/who-is-the-rightful-copyright-holder-of-images-to-windows-components)

[Is vectorizing an image copyright theft if the image is not CC/Public domain?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5496/is-vectorizing-an-image-copyright-theft-if-the-image-is-not-cc-public-domain)

[Is it OK to include a stylized reproduction of a copyrighted painting in a design?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/12956/is-it-ok-to-include-a-stylized-reproduction-of-a-copyrighted-painting-in-a-desig)

Comment: Thanks for the information. It looks like Apple actually provides graphics for this purpose which can be found here: [link](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/marketing/index.html)

Answer (score 4):

Apple provide images of their devices that can be used for marketing purposes.

They can all be found here (requires developer log in to see):
https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/marketing/index.html

So in your specific case, it doesn't matter... you can create an image of your app running on an iPhone or iPad, and Apple are OK with that.